# Jersey numbers using digits 40000000

Tags: probability

A family of eight sits in a row during a basketball game wearing basketball jerseys with a single digit from 1 to 8 printed on the back.

Find the probability that the 8-digit code formed by the digits on the jerseys is
(i) an odd number greater than 40000000,
(ii) greater than 40000000, given that it is an odd number.

My answers:

(i)  If first digit are 4/ 6/ 8:
Number of ways :  3C1 * 6! *  4C1 = 8640

```
 If first digit is 5/ 7:

  Number of ways :  2 * 6! *  3C1 = 4320 
  
 Total number of ways: 8640 + 4320 = 12960

 Probability = 12960 / 8! = 9/28
```

(ii) Number of ways to arrange odd numbers:  7! * 4C1 = 20160

```
9/28 divide 20160/ 8! = 9/14
```

Are my answers correct? If incorrect, what is wrong? Thanks

Comment: Can the jersey numbers repeat?

Comment: Why bother writing with "C1" here?  Why write "4C1" when you could have just simply written... "4".

Comment: Assuming each digit occurs exactly once and all orders are equally likely, your answers are correct... though the presentation could be cleaned up.  When writing here [MathJax and $\LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) are preferred.  That is admittedly less common to use for intro-level homework submissions, but getting in the habit now will make it easier for when you get to higher level courses where it may become mandatory.

Comment: thank you noted. No repeat of digits.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the $8×7=56$ possible first and last digit combinations, $4×7=28$ are odd. We can count manually that $18$ of those $28$ combinations have first digit $4$ or more:

```
4-1 4-3 4-5 4-7
5-1 5-3 5-7
6-1 6-3 6-5 6-7
7-1 7-3 7-5
8-1 8-3 8-5 8-7
```

Thus the answer for (a) is $\frac{18}{56}=\frac9{28}$ and that for (b) is $\frac{18}{28}=\frac9{14}$ – you are correct for both, but I have demonstrated a simpler method based on the fact that *the middle six digits are irrelevant*.